# Are there any realistic AIs in movies?

Tags: science-fiction

Most of so-called Artificial Intelligences in Sci-Fi movies, in my opinion, are too advanced, too much human. They are just a kind of human with mechanical body.

As of 2018, "realistic" artificial intelligence is: something similar to human but its behavior and decision process is totally different from  humanity. 
Are there any movies which describe such weird difference? I think "2001 a space odyssey" is the one, anything else?

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! I have a feeling that this will end up getting closed as a "recommendation" question, regardless of whether you're actually looking for specific recommendations or not. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: Even if it's not a recommendation question (which it is), it's both too broad and opiniion based (who defines realistic?)

Comment: What do you mean by "something similar to human" if its behaviour and decision process is totally different from humanity?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

You probably don't notice because you're looking out for C3PO or HAL.

But most AIs that are around IRL are integrated part of a computer systems... e.g. facial recognition, speech recognition, self-driving cars, aeroplane autopilot systems, NPCs in computer games, OCR, etc.

So whenever one of these things appears in a movie, you're seeing a realistic A.I.